# Frequency of occurence for every possible combination of values in two columns on the same row

Tags: vba, excel, frequency

I have a data-set with Product 1 in Column A and Product 2 in Column B.

I would like to build a new table which counts the number of rows on which every possible combination of Product 1 and Product 2 occur. (Preferably regardless of the order in which they occur, but I can clean that up after if needed)

I can build this manually, however I am dealing with hundreds of possible combinations and would like to automate the process with a macro or any other recommendations anyone has.

Example of raw data:

```
Product 1   Product 2
Cheese          Apple
Crackers    Sausage
Cheese          Sausage
Crackers    Sausage
Apple           Crackers
Apple           Cheese
Cheese          Apple
Cherry          Apple
```

Example of new summarized table:

```
Combo               | Count of Combo Occurrences
Cheese and Apple    | 3
Cheese and Sausage  | 1
Cherry and Apple    | 1
Crackers and Sausage| 2
Apple and Crackers  | 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hungry and intrigued

Comment: Now this is a fun little problem

Comment: @urdearboy I’ll go get some cheese if you bring apples

Comment: I wish I could treat you all to drinks and snacks just for taking a look and trying to help in solving this... it's driving me nuts.

Comment: @user3088527 this is a big ask.  And usually, questions without code and specific error resulting from that code get closed and down voted.  Do you have any code you have tried?  If so could you post it in your original post using [edit]?

Comment: I kind of hope it doesn't get closed, I want to take a stab at it although my solution will probably be bloated

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 it is late in the afternoon in the U.S. so site traffic is down at the moment so you probably will have time.  I would approach it by creating a dictionary of all the unique products.  Then double loop through that to get the unique combos.  then I would use countifs to return the counts.  but that is just me.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817714/finding-combinations-and-counting-them-in-excel

Comment: @ArnovanBoven whelp, thats disappointing lol. and it's even dead simple

Comment: with the link just change the formula for combination column to: `=IF(B2>A2,A2,B2) & " and " & IF(B2>A2,B2,A2)` this will match regardless of order.

Comment: I think you owe @ArnovanBoven some cheese

Comment: It is dead simple once you reach advanced Excel skills like array formulas. I never got to that level of wizardry :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! You're all amazing.  Sorry for not providing attempted code, I really wasn't sure where to start.  Although admittedly I had thought of the PivotTable solution after I posted this.  But I prefer the Array solution and it gets my toes wet in the world of Arrays, which is a plus!

Comment: @ArnovanBoven I could be mistaken, but I don't think pivot tables would group "Apples and Oranges" with "Oranges and Apples".  The first step in the answer you linked is to create the groups by concatenating two values together.

Comment: @JosephC it works with the modification provided by Scott Craner by alphabetizing in the formula in the combination column

Comment: Ahh yup, that would do it.  :)

Comment: @JosephC that may well be, all I did was provide the possible duplicate link as the q was the same (and tested the array formula part just for fun)

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Good stuff.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some poor soul will need this in VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ComboOccurences()

    ' Remember to check Microsoft Scripting Runtime in References!
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, LastRow As Integer
    Dim ColAB As String, ColBA As String

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ColAB = Range("A" & i).Value & " and " & Range("B" & i).Value
        ColBA = Range("B" & i).Value & " and " & Range("A" & i).Value
        If Not dict.Exists(ColAB) And Not dict.Exists(ColBA) Then
            dict.Add (ColAB), 1
        ElseIf dict.Exists(ColAB) Then
            dict(ColAB) = dict(ColAB) + 1
        ElseIf dict.Exists(ColBA) Then
            dict(ColBA) = dict(ColBA) + 1
        End If
    Next

    r = 2
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Range("D" & r).Value = dict.Keys(i)
        Range("E" & r).Value = dict.Items(i)
        r = r + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Final Result]

Hope this will help somebody!

Comment: It might be a bit cleaner if you store A and B into separate variables but alphabetically. As in the first variable is always the “first” alphabetically so that you don’t have to check multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but your question seemed like a fun exercise.  For kicks I decided to add an extra layer of complexity by writing it to use any size range & outputting the results to a specified range (or sheet).

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    Call CountUniqueCombinations(Range("A2:D7"), Range("F2"))
End Sub

Private Sub CountUniqueCombinations(ByVal SourceRange As Range, ByVal DestinationRange As Range)
    Dim oRowIndex As Long
    Dim oColIndex As Long
    Dim oRow As New Collection

    For oRowIndex = 0 To SourceRange.Rows.Count - 1
        oValue = ""
        Set oRow = Nothing

        ' Sort Current Row (Output to String)
        For oColIndex = 1 To SourceRange.Columns.Count
            oRow.Add SourceRange(oRowIndex + 1, oColIndex).Value
        Next
        oValue = SortCollection(oRow)

        ' See if Sorted row already Exists if so +1
        Dim oDestRowIndex As Long
        Dim oFound As Boolean
        oFound = False
        For oDestRowIndex = 1 To DestinationRange.Rows.Count
            If DestinationRange(oDestRowIndex, 1).Value = oValue Then
                DestinationRange(oDestRowIndex, 2).Value = CInt(DestinationRange(oDestRowIndex, 2).Value) + 1
                oFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' if Sorted row doesn't exist add it
        If Not oFound Then
            DestinationRange(DestinationRange.Rows.Count, 1) = oValue
            DestinationRange(DestinationRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1) = 1
            Set DestinationRange = DestinationRange.Resize(DestinationRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Private Function SortCollection(ByVal oCollection As Collection) As String
    Dim oX As Long, oY As Long
    Dim oTempValue As String

    For oX = 1 To oCollection.Count - 1
        For oY = oX + 1 To oCollection.Count
            If oCollection(oX) > oCollection(oY) Then
                oTempValue = oCollection(oY)
                oCollection.Remove (oY)
                oCollection.Add oTempValue, oTempValue, oX
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For oX = 1 To oCollection.Count
        If oCollection.Item(oX) <> "" Then
            SortCollection = SortCollection & oCollection.Item(oX) & " & "
        End If
    Next

    SortCollection = Left(SortCollection, Len(SortCollection) - 3)
End Function
```